# What is the issue about fr + fd in filament document?

Tags: pbr, google-filament

I am learning pbr theory by the document of filament.

In the [Energy gain in diffuse reflectance](https://google.github.io/filament/Filament.html#materialsystem/improvingthebrdfs/energygainindiffusereflectance) section, it add a **[TODO: talk about the issue with fr+fd]**.

I can't find any resources about this.

Can anyone tell me about this? Or give me some resources to learn.

Thanks.